# Why do these non-constant expressions not throw an error when used as an array dimension?

Tags: c++, constexpr

I'm currently plodding along through C++ Primer by Stanley Lippman, and in an example for `constexpr` functions learned that a function like

```
constexpr size_t geom(size_t cnt) { return new_sz() * cnt * 10;}
```

is not required to return a constant expression, and only does so if it's argument is a constant expression. Hence, if I try to use the return of `geom` with a non-constant argument in a context which requires a constant expression like as the dimension in an array initialization, the compiler should produce an error indicating `geom` is not a constant expression.

So I would think, as per the book's example with nearly identical code, that `arr` would be okay in the following example, and `a2` would produce a compile-time error

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<cctype>
using std::cin; using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::string;
using std::vector; using std::end; using std::begin; using std::getline;
using std::initializer_list;

constexpr int new_sz() { return 42;}
constexpr size_t geom(size_t cnt) { return new_sz() * cnt * 10;}

int main()
{
    int arr[geom(2)];
    int i = 10;
    int a2[geom(i)];
    return 0;
}
```

But this compiles fine. In fact, I can even make `geom` and `new_sz()` non-`constexpr` functions and it still compiles fine. I though maybe `geom` was somehow implicitly being made into a `constexpr` function so I went as far as to write this clearly non-`constexpr` function `test`

```
int test(int a, int b){ 
    if (a > b) return a;
    else return b;
}
```

and use it in an array initialization, and it works as well. What is going on? Is this compiler-specific? I am using GCC 4.9.2 32-bit release.  I took a look at the [cpp reference for array declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) to see if I was maybe lost on what the dimension could be, but it is supposed to be an integral constant expression... I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

Comment: Compile with -pedantic. If you want to test that it can produce a constant expression, `static_assert` is always an option.

Comment: I suspect you're using GCC? There's a compiler extension that allows VLAs, and IIRC it's enabled by default.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am using GCC, I'll look into that, thanks. Apologies for not finding the duplicate.